# 'Namespace' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, python-module

Attempting to pass an undetermined amount of integers using argparse. When I input: **py main.py 3 2**

```
    %%writefile main.py

import sorthelper
import argparse


integers = 0

#top-level parser creation
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("For sorting integers")

nargs = '+' #-> gathers cmd line arguments into a list
args = parser.add_argument('-f', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+', help='yada yada yada')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(sorthelper.sortNumbers(args))


%%writefile sorthelper.py

def sortNumbers(args):
    sorted(args)
```

Error Namespace Argument is not iterable

I think is is because I am passing an argument that is not of the correct type. After reading through all the documentation I could find I cannot figure out how to make this work. I want the program to sort the numbers I am passing.

Comment: `sorthelper.sortNumber(args)` should call the imported function and pass it the `args` variable.  It's no different from calling any other imported function.

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] for tips. For example, if you're looking for debugging help, you need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Okay so. 1) If you weren't using argparse, and instead wanted to use specific hard-coded values to call `sortNumbers`, would you be able to do that? 2) Did you try checking, after `args = parser.parse_args()`, what `args` actually looks like? Did you try reading the documentation to see how it's supposed to work? 3) Okay, now put it together - get the information out of `args`, and use it to make a call to `sortNumbers`. *Where exactly are you stuck*?

Comment: Where you put `args.func(args)`, *what are you expecting this to mean*? Again, try looking at the documentation. What kind of thing is `args`? What data does it contain? How can you get the necessary information out of it, according to the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`parser.parse_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method) returns [a `Namespace` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace), which is an object whose attributes represent the flags that were parsed. It is not iterable.

It seems like you want to get the command-line arguments given after `-f`, in which case you would take *that particular flag* out of the `Namespace` object:

```
print(sorthelper.sortNumbers(args.f))
```

---

Also, your code as you currently have it will print `None`, because `sortNumbers()` doesn't return anything. The built-in `sorted()` function *does not sort in place* (though `list.sort()` does, if you want to use that), so you have to actually do

```
def sortNumbers(args):
    return sorted(args)
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance with argparse. You were able to help me finally move on from that. I had trouble later with printing the function but I finally managed. I ended up using:        `answer = sorthelper.sortNumbers(args.f)
print(answer)`